# Animating height in CSS the right way

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I'm learning JS and there is this task:
[before clicking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GNdMl.jpg)
[after clicking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohq0E.jpg)

Basically the button has to make the second image slide to uncover the first one. The way it's thaught in the course is to just animate the top image's height, which I know is a bad practice.

Is there a way to do this efficiently without having to manually handle all of the elements' positions?

Comment: you should provide us with your code's working snippet

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Using css transitions and transforms can give you the same results.

For example:

HTML:

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img class="top" src="image.jpg" alt="">
  <img class="bottom" src="image2.jpg" alt="">
  <button id="animate">Animate</button>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.wrapper {
  position:relative;
  width:300px;
  height:200px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
    
.wrapper img {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  transition:transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
    
.wrapper.view .top {
  transform:translateX(-100%);
}
```

Javascript:

```js
const wrapper = document.querySelector(".wrapper");
const animate = document.getElementBy("animate");
animate.addEventListener('click', () => {
  wrapper.classList.toggle('view');
});
```